# Opening url with Cocoa button causes memory leak

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, nsworkspace

I have a button in my Cocoa app that opens a url in the web browser.  If the browser is not open when the button is pressed then I get a memory leak.  If the browser is already open then I do not get the memory leak.

The code for the button is:

```
- (IBAction)goToWebsite:(id)sender {
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/?apiref=123"]];
}
```

The memory leak as described in Instruments is:

```
Leaked Object = Malloc 2.00 KB
Number = 1
Address = 0x7f8003039600
Size = 2.00 KB
Responsible Library = libsystem_sandbox.dylib
Responsible Frame = sandbox_extension_issue
```

How do I prevent this memory leak?

This is my first time testing an app for leaks so any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. I'm using Xcode 4.3.3 and OSX 10.7.4

Comment: Would enabling App Sandboxing and checking the Incoming/Outgoing Network Connections prevent the leak from occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can really do about this other than file it with apple as a bug

Comment: Is it a bug or is it something wrong with my program?  I have a feeling that I'm not sandboxing my app properly.

Comment: Well have you looked in the Console app to see if you are violating the sandbox?

Comment: Does sandboxing not allow the use of Safari?

Comment: Asking `NSWorkspace` to open a URL like this is perfectly acceptable for a sandboxed app.

Comment: Yeah I agree. The app was accepted in the app store so apparently it is an accepted method for a sandboxed app.